# SARSA algorithm for average reward problems

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

My question is about using the SARSA algorithm in reinforcement learning for an *undiscounted*, continuing (non-episodic) problem (can it be used for such a problem?)

I have been studying the textbook by Sutton and Barto, and they show how to modify the Q-learning algorithm so that it can be used for undiscounted problems.  They refer to the new algorithm (for undiscounted problems) as R-learning, in Chapter 6.7.  Basically, in R-learning, the update rule for Q(s,a) on each iteration is:

Q(s,a) = Q(s,a) + alpha * [r - rho + max_a{Q(s',a)} - Q(s,a)]

Here, rho is updated on each iteration only if a greedy action is chosen at state s.  The update rule for rho is:

rho = rho + beta * [r - rho + max_a{Q(s',a)} - max_a{Q(s,a)}]

(Here, alpha and beta are learning parameters.)  Now, my question is to do with SARSA, rather than Q-learning.  I want to modify the SARSA algorithm so that it is suitable for average reward (undiscounted) problems, in the same way that the Q-learning was modified to be used for average reward problems (I don't know if this is possible?).  However, in the literature I cannot find an explanation of exactly how SARSA should be modified for an average reward problem.

Here is my guess for how SARSA should be used in an undiscounted problem.  I would guess that the update rule should be:

Q(s,a) = Q(s,a) + alpha * [r - rho + Q(s',a') - Q(s,a)],

where a' is the action actually chosen at state s.  This seems fairly obvious.  But how should rho be updated?  My guess is that since SARSA is an on-policy algorithm, rho should always be updated on each iteration - regardless of whether or not a greedy action is chosen at s - and the update rule should simply be:

rho = rho + beta * [r - rho + Q(s',a') - Q(s,a)].

Could somebody tell me if this is correct?  Or should rho still be updated based on the optimal actions at the states s and s'?

Comment: Another reason why [LaTeX is necessary in StackOverflow...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4152/192283)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the problem is that an undiscounted non-episodic task is an ill conditioned problem, because the expected reward is divergent (unless rewards have some property which makes them diminishing in the future).

EDIT: I'm sorry, I've look-up the referenced chapter in the book, and noticed that indeed the R-learning IS a method to tackle undiscounted non-episodic tasks.

AD REM: I think that the idea behind updating rho in such manner is to estimate the average reward of the *current* policy. Therefore I'm guessing that even though SARSA is an on-policy method, you should update rho only if greedy action has been chosen. And that's because if you want to accurately estimate the average reward of the *current* policy, you should take into account only events that would occur when you would be following this policy. Events that occur as a result of exploration steps do not represent an accurate sample of "what's this policy is worth". That's of course only an intuitive argument - I don't have any experience with R-learning nor did I analysed this issue formally.

Comment: I would suggest elaborating on your posts in the future. While this could be an answer, it needs more thorough explanations to truly be spectacular.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've updated the answer - its initial version didn't make any sense unfortunately :)

Comment: And now this is a much better answer :] Thank you!